# Runtime error 438 when trying to run a VBA code for duplicate emails in Oulook365

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to write a code to find duplicate emails. I've found a snippet on the web and tried to use it.

It works ok on some Outlook folders and on some it gives me the [runtime error 438](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/object-doesn-t-support-this-property-or-method-error-438). As I am not savvy in VBA I can't figure out the problem.

I get the error on this line:

```
strKey = objItem.Subject & "," & objItem.Body & "," & objItem.SentOn
```

Can you give me advice on how to fix this error?

This is the code:

```
Sub RemoveDuplicateItems()
    Dim objFolder As Folder
    Dim objDictionary As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim strKey As String

    Set objDictionary = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    'Select a source folder
    Set objFolder = Outlook.Application.Session.PickFolder

    If Not (objFolder Is Nothing) Then
       For i = objFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
           Set objItem = objFolder.Items.Item(i)

           Select Case objFolder.DefaultItemType
                  'Check email subject, body and sent time
                  Case olMailItem
                       strKey = objItem.Subject & "," & objItem.Body & "," & objItem.SentOn
                  'Check appointment subject, start time, duration, location and body
                  Case olAppointmentItem
                       strKey = objItem.Subject & "," & objItem.Start & "," & objItem.Duration & "," & objItem.Location & "," & objItem.Body
                  'Check contact full name and email address
                  Case olContactItem
                       strKey = objItem.FullName & "," & objItem.Email1Address & "," & objItem.Email2Address & "," & objItem.Email3Address
                  'Check task subject, start date, due date and body
                  Case olTaskItem
                       strKey = objItem.Subject & "," & objItem.StartDate & "," & objItem.DueDate & "," & objItem.Body
           End Select

           strKey = Replace(strKey, ", ", Chr(32))

           'Remove the duplicate items
           If objDictionary.Exists(strKey) = True Then
              objItem.Delete
           Else
              objDictionary.Add strKey, True
           End If
       Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You're assuming that all the items in the folder are actually the default type... you want to check the type of *each item*.

Comment: Thanks BigBen for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Dim objItem As Object
> ```

Any member call made against this `objItem` object is going to be late-bound. That is, resolved at run-time. Meaning, the compiler has no idea whether `objItem.Whatever` is valid or not, and does not care (yay late binding!). Unfortunately this also means it cannot help you, and if you invoke a member that VBA can't find on that object at run-time, that's when and how error 438 "can't find that member" is raised.

One solution could be to carefully review which members you're calling in which `Case` branch.

Another solution could be to switch to *early binding* as soon as you know what type you're dealing with, and get back to compile-time safety - the `Outlook` type library is referenced, the compiler already knows what the Outlook types are.

Also, `Select Case objFolder.DefaultItemType` is constant for every iteration of the loop, you'll want to change that. Using `TypeOf...Is` you could validate the runtime type of the `objItem` object against compile-time types:

```
Select Case True
    Case TypeOf objItem Is Outlook.ContactItem
        '...

    Case TypeOf objItem Is Outlook.TaskItem
        '...

    Case TypeOf objItem Is Outlook.AppointmentItem
        '...

    Case TypeOf objItem Is Outlook.MailItem
        Dim currentMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
        Set currentMailItem = objItem '<~ cast the object to MailItem

        strKey = currentMailItem.Subject & "," & currentMailItem.Body & "," & currentMailItem.SentOn
```

...I'm not very familiar with the Outlook object model, but it looks like a `Task` is also a `MailItem` so the ordering of clauses might be important (test the more specific types first, broader all-encompassing types last).

Comment: many thanks. you're right, i had "tasks" in email list. when i removed those - it worked. now i'm working on changing the code based on you suggestion